# Saving/Loading QGIS style .qml and avoid specified symbology

Tags: qgis, python, symbology

Is it possible to save QGIS styles without the symbology style? This may seem like a strange question, but I am trying to automatically set the ValueMap widget under layer properties via a plugin for QGIS 2.0. I'm not able to set the key:value pair in this version, as it's not possible until version 2.2.

What i'd like to do is save the .qml file without any symbology style specified. This is so that when the .qml is loaded via pyQGIS, the user identified symbology doesn't change with it (only the layer property widgets).

I've tried to edit the .qml style file by removing the information pertaining to "symbols". This results in changing the symbology to a simple black line, not remaining unchanged as set by user as I was hoping.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to open the .qml style via **Notepad** or a similar program and edit all symbology-related terms.

Comment: @Joseph If you've had success doing this, I would really like some suggestions on which parts should be edited, etc.

Comment: Apologies but I never had to do this (I don't even know if my suggestion is possible), hopefully someone will provide an answer.